# jupyter notebook doesn't open after catalina

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, macos-catalina

After updating my mac to catalina jupyter notebook doesn't open anymore. I disinstall anaconda and install the new 2019.10 release but unsuccessfully.

I tried to disinstall anaconda and reinstall new 2019.10 release.

The terminal gives the following error message

> 2019-10-18 23:11:38.333 osascript[2121:39758] Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '
>   -[__NSDictionaryM __setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil'
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException